# filter defects by dates, selected from combobox rally

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

Want to filter defects by three conditions
Open defects, defect release start date, and defect release end date.
For release start date and release end date I am selecting from date combobox.

Below is my code

```
            _prepareChart: function() {
                that = this;
                console.log("start date", that._startDate);
                console.log("end date", that._endDate);
                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                    model: 'Defect',
                    //fetch: ['Release'],
                    limit: Infinity,
                    field: 'State',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    storeConfig: {
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'State',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: "Open"
                            },
                            {
                                property: 'Release.ReleaseStartDate',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: that._startDate
                            },
                            {
                                property: 'Release.ReleaseDate',
                                operator: '<=',
                                value: that._endDate                                
                            }
                        ],  
                    },      
                    listeners: {
                        load: this._onDataLoaded,
                        //load: this._onDataLoadedfirst,
                        scope: this
                    }
                }); 
            },
```

Below is the application screen from where I am selecting the dates

[image]

Comment: How is your code not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @APerson - thanks for reply, it working but the data shown is not correct. Can you see the code, ReleaseStartDate and ReleaseDate dates comparison I am doing is correct or wrong.

Comment: @APerson -  As there are no Open defects for particular project, but it shows total no. of defects regardless of filters.

Comment: got it fixed.                                                   `start_date = Rally.util.DateTime.format(new Date(that._startDate), 'Y-m-d');
     end_date = Rally.util.DateTime.format(new Date(that._endDate), 'Y-m-d');` changed the dates format required by rally, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use javascript [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method as in [this example](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-defects-of-current-sprint-with-tasks/blob/master/App.js)

```
var today = new Date().toISOString();
   Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store', {
      models: ['UserStory','Defect'],
      fetch: ['Owner', 'FormattedID','Name','ScheduleState','Tasks'],
       autoLoad: true,
      filters : [
         {
            property: 'Iteration.StartDate',
            operator: '<=',
            value: today
          },
          {
             property: 'Iteration.EndDate',
             operator: '>=',
             value: today
          }
        ],
        listeners: {
           load: this._onDataLoaded,
           scope: this
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nick, For the answer I will try this too and I made it working with the below code.

got it fixed already.

```
start_date = Rally.util.DateTime.format(new Date(that._startDate), 'Y-m-d');
end_date = Rally.util.DateTime.format(new Date(that._endDate), 'Y-m-d');
```

changed the dates format required by rally, thanks